# Add value when checkbox is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox, when it is checked, I simply want it to add 2 to a specific field called amount10.

```js
$('#checkbox2').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("#amount10").val() + 2;
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    deliverySliderValue = value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by the first line of code inside if condition? select that element, then set its value by selecting the same with parseInt and add 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the value back to the element.

```js
$('#checkbox2').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    value = parseInt($("#amount10").val()) + 2;
    $("#amount10").val(value);
    //var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    //deliverySliderValue = value;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">

<input id="amount10" value='1' />
```

Comment: what would be the reason for me to click the checkbox 2x for it to update?

Comment: `if (this.checked) {` this condition means that increase will execute only when it is a check action. If you remove that `if` then it will work on every click.